# Strange bug with tabbed content box, prevent click and multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which is going to have multiple tabbed content boxes on but I cant seem to get my box working when theres more than one, Also i need to disable the "A" tag with the class disable on only for some reason everything Ive tried I cant seem to prevent the event!

Ive made a fiddle if anyone can help me out, thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/j6A94/

Comment: Your code is working after removing the sorrounding script tags in JS. here is the updated fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/j6A94/1/

Comment: It isnt working, The tab that should be disabled is still available to click and the second tabbed box isnt working correctly?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j6A94/2/    this fixed the click issue with disabled tab. Can you elaborate whats wrong with your second tabbed box

Comment: Hi, thats birlliant thanks @JQone, the second one doesnt seem to work, I need it to work like the first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...Here is the working solution

http://jsfiddle.net/j6A94/3/

$(".tabbed-box .tabs li a") will select `a` from both the tabs. So you need to limit the selection to the specific tab that you are clicking